# Finding difference between two dates times in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

Problem Statement : 
I have to validate a form having fields 'Start Date' and 'End Date'.

Validation Constraint : 
Difference between these two dates must not be less than 24 hours.

Example:
Invalid case :
SDate : "01-10-2012 11:59"
EDate : ""02-10-2012 00:00"

SDate : "01-10-2012 02:20"
EDate : ""02-10-2012 02:00"

Valid Case :

SDate : "01-10-2012 02:20"
EDate : ""02-10-2012 03:30"

Note : These two date objects have time value also.

Comment: are those dates 12 hours, or 1 month apart ;-)

Comment: dd-mm-yyyy the dd is part diff which makes ya think its a day's difference but the time makes it less than a day apart

Comment: yeah, I figured they were dd-mm-yyyy.  The problem is that's not a proper internationally recognised format.  In the US they'd assume that was mm-dd-yyyy.  The best format for this is ISO8601 which uses yyyy-mm-dd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have parsed the 2 strings and created the corresponding `Date` object, you only have to use :

```js
function isValid(startDate, endDate) {
  return endDate - startDate > 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
}
```

Comment: new Date("01-10-2012 05:30") gives Invalid Date object for which getTime() is NaN

Comment: Yes, when you use `new Date(dateAsString)` or `Date.parse(dateAsString)` the *dateAsString* must be represented as an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 date. That why, I started the answer with *Once you have parsed the 2 strings and created the corresponding `Date`*

Comment: @AlexandreArdhuin there's no need to call `getTime()` - JS will automatically invoke `.valueOf()` when you use a math operation on a `Date` which does the same thing.

Comment: sorry can you please help me in parsing them to the formats ya have mentioned. Thanks for the info :)

Comment: As suggested by an other answer, you can use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com) and particullary [parsing functionnality](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/). For your case, someting like `moment(stringAsDate, "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm")` should give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). It almost certainly does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
        function(start, end, unit){
            var denom = 1,
                diff = end.getTime() - start.getTime();

            if(unit == 's'){ 
                denom = 1000;
            }
            else if(unit == 'm'){
                denom = 1000*60;
            }
            else if(unit == 'h'){
                denom = 1000*60*60;
            }
            return Math.round(diff/denom);
        }
```

unit can be 's' - seconds, 'm' - minutes, 'h' - days. You can extend this for your choice: days, months ect.

You should also parse your dates to javascript `Date` object first. Do you need help with that?

Date parsing from your format:

```
var p = "01-10-2012 05:30".match(/(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4}) (\d{2}):(\d{2})/);
parsedDate = new Date(parseInt(p[3]) - 1900, parseInt(p[2]) - 1, p[1], p[4], p[5]);
```

Comment: yes i did do the following to parse to Date Object: 
new Date("01-10-2012 05:30") gives Invalid Date object for which getTime() is NaN

Comment: @VyacheslavVoronchuk not all browsers support ISO8601 format.  The only universally supported format AFAIK is RFC2822 format, so IME it's better to deconstruct the string (as you have) but then use the constructor that takes the six separate fields.

Comment: @VyacheslavVoronchuk if you do that you must however also subtract 1900 from the year, and 1 from the month.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to calculate the difference and perform your validation:

```
 Date.daysBetween = function( date1, date2 ) {
  //Get 1 day in milliseconds
  var one_day=1000*60*60*24;

  // Convert both dates to milliseconds
  var date1_ms = date1.getTime();
  var date2_ms = date2.getTime();

  // Calculate the difference in milliseconds
  var difference_ms = date2_ms - date1_ms;
  //take out milliseconds
  difference_ms = difference_ms/1000;
  var seconds = Math.floor(difference_ms % 60);
  difference_ms = difference_ms/60; 
  var minutes = Math.floor(difference_ms % 60);
  difference_ms = difference_ms/60; 
  var hours = Math.floor(difference_ms % 24);  
  var days = Math.floor(difference_ms/24);

  return days + ' days, ' + hours + ' hours, ' + minutes + ' minutes, and ' + seconds + ' seconds';
}
```

Comment: that's _way_ over complicated - he just wants to know whether it exceeds 24 hours, not by how much.

Comment: This shows how to get the difference in different units, he does not need to use all of them, can use just the difference in hours and do his validation.

Comment: If you've got two date objects the required test is a _one liner_.

Answer (score 0):

The hard part is converting the strings into valid `Date` objects, particularly since you are using a non-standard date format.

I would advise using a third party library which can cope with that format, or use simple string manipulation and use the version of the `Data` constructor that takes six individual fields for each of *(year, month, date, hour, minute, seconds)*.

Having done that, testing whether two JavaScript `Date` objects are more than 24 hours apart is the easy bit - just take their numeric value and check whether it's more than 86400000 (the number of milliseconds in a day).

```
var t1 = new Date(Y1, M1, D1, hh1, mm1, ss1);
var t2 = new Date(Y2, M2, D2, hh2, mm2, ss2);

var valid = (t2 - t1) >= 86400000;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  /** Method: getDateObject
   * 
   * Description: 
   * gives date object from string 
   * @param dateString
   * @param separator used
   * @returns corresponding date object 
   */

function getDateObject(dateString, parseFormat) {
//This function return a date object after accepting

 if(dateString!=null && dateString!=undefined && dateString!="")
 {
  var dateFormat = sessvars.currentUser.options.dateFormat;
  if(parseFormat.length==0)
      parseFormat = [dateFormat + " HH:mm:ss", dateFormat + " HH:mm",dateFormat];

  var dtObject = Date.parseExact(dateString, parseFormat);  
  return dtObject;
 }
else
  return dateString;
}
```

Ok Thanx a lot guys for your valuable advice and suggestions. I have got a solution using a mix of your ideas.

Solution:

1.Made a custom function which return date object according to the format specified.

2.Now getTime() which gives milliseconds value.

3.SDate.getTime() - EDate.getTime() < 24*3600*1000

Example :

getDateObject("01-10-2012 05:30",[]).getTime() - getDateObject("02-10-2012 05:30",[]).getTime() < 24*3600*1000