# JavaScript date difference correction

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function that will calculate time between two  date / time but I am having a small issue with the return.

Here is the way I collect the information.

**Start Date**
**Start Time**
**Ending Date**
**Ending Time**
**Hours**

And here is the function that calculates the dates and times:

```js
function calculate (form) {
    var d1 = document.getElementById("date1").value;
    var d2 = document.getElementById("date2").value;
    var t1 = document.getElementById("time1").value;
    var t2 = document.getElementById("time2").value;
    var dd1 = d1 + " " + t1;
    var dd2 = d2 + " " + t2;
    var date1 = new Date(dd1);
    var date2 = new Date(dd2);
    var sec = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
    if (isNaN(sec)) {
        alert("Input data is incorrect!");
        return;
    }
    if (sec < 0) {
        alert("The second date ocurred earlier than the first one!");
        return;
    }
    var second = 1000,
        minute = 60 * second,
        hour = 60 * minute,
        day = 24 * hour;
    var hours = Math.floor(sec / hour);
    sec -= hours * hour;
    var minutes = Math.floor(sec / minute);
    sec -= minutes * minute;
    var seconds = Math.floor(sec / second);
    var min = Math.floor((minutes * 100) / 60);
    document.getElementById("result").value = hours + '.' + min;
}
```

If I put in todays date for both date fields and then 14:30 in the first time field and 15:35 in the second time field the result is shown as 1.8 and it should be 1.08

I didn't write this function but I am wondering if someone could tell me how to make that change?

Thank you.

Comment: asked before.. many times: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696654/get-total-time-difference-between-two-dates-using-php

Comment: @Hardy true, it has, but that particular question is a bad example. It's in PHP.

Comment: yea, divide it by one :)

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413568/finding-difference-between-two-dates-times-in-javascript/13413718#13413718

Comment: that was just joke.. for @Doorhandle comment.."divide it by 1" what happens when you divide number by 1 = nothing :)

Comment: @Hardy Typo :P You could put **document.getElementById("result").value = hours + '.' + min / 10** which would turn .8 to .08

Comment: @Hardy Yea :P I'm just going to say it was a typo, I was thinking 10 but I put 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see why 15:35 - 14:30 = 1.08 is useful?

Try this instead:

```
function timediff( date1, date2 ) {
      //Get 1 day in milliseconds
      var one_day=1000*60*60*24;

      // Convert both dates to milliseconds
      var date1_ms = date1.getTime();
      var date2_ms = date2.getTime();

      // Calculate the difference in milliseconds
      var difference_ms = date2_ms - date1_ms;
      //take out milliseconds
      difference_ms = difference_ms/1000;
      var seconds = Math.floor(difference_ms % 60);
      difference_ms = difference_ms/60; 
      var minutes = Math.floor(difference_ms % 60);
      difference_ms = difference_ms/60; 
      var hours = Math.floor(difference_ms % 24);  
      var days = Math.floor(difference_ms/24);

      return [days,hours,minutes,seconds];
    }

function calculate (form) {
    var d1 = document.getElementById("date1").value;
    var d2 = document.getElementById("date2").value;
    var t1 = document.getElementById("time1").value;
    var t2 = document.getElementById("time2").value;
    var dd1 = d1 + " " + t1;
    var dd2 = d2 + " " + t2;
    var date1 = new Date(dd1);
    var date2 = new Date(dd2);

    var diff = timediff(date1, date2);

    document.getElementById("result").value = diff[1] + ':' + diff[2];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the only issue you are having is that the minutes are not padded by zeroes. If this is the case, you can pad the value of `min` with zeroes using this little trick:

```
("00" + min).slice(-2)
```

Comment: Your answer bwtter than mine,+1.

Answer (score 0):

Verify if number of minutes is less than 10 and if it is then append an additional zero in front. Follow similar approach for seconds.